# Domain of $x^{m/n}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

In my high school math class the teacher taught us the law that the domain of the function $x^{\frac{m}{n}}$ Is $x\ge0$ .

My question is... Why is that? Especially when it means that the domain of $\sqrt[5]{x}$ is different from the domain of $x^\frac{1}{5}$

BTW... this is my first question here and my first LaTeX script so don't be too harsh on me

Comment: For most manipulations it is the safest choice to take the domain to be $[0,\infty)$ although in some cases the power can be defined for negative numbers as well (as a real number).

Comment: One of the problems with fractional exponents is that books and people are not always sufficiently explicit with what $x^{\frac{m}{n}}$ means. Is this the $m$'th power of an $n$'th root or the $n$'th root of an $m$'th power? Note that since $\frac{1}{5} = \frac{2}{10},$ we would presumably want $x^{\frac{1}{5}} = x^{\frac{2}{10}},$ but this is not the case if the root comes first and $x$ is negative.

Comment: Thanks!!!! now I can die in peace!